# xslt printing a name from a node reference

Tags: xslt

This is my first attempt at xslt.

I am setting up fields to print on a PDF form.

I have this:

```
    <Field>
        <Name>Accident1_Name</Name>
        <Value>
            <xsl:value-of
                          select="PersPolicy/AccidentViolation[1]/@DriverRef" />
        </Value>
        <Type>Tx</Type>
    </Field>
```

But this just give me the driver number.

in XML it looks like this

```
<AccidentViolation id="N196" DriverRef="N86" saved="true">
  <AccidentViolationCd id="N202">NO</AccidentViolationCd>
  <AccidentViolationDt id="N198">2012-04-05</AccidentViolationDt>
  <PlaceIncident id="N201">Tampa Florida</PlaceIncident>
  <ConvictionDt id="N199">2012-04-05</ConvictionDt>
  <AccidentViolationRecordTypeCd id="N200">AAM</AccidentViolationRecordTypeCd>
</AccidentViolation>

  <PersDriver id="N86" saved="true">
  <GeneralPartyInfo id="N88">
    <NameInfo id="N89">
      <PersonName id="N90">
        <Surname id="N93">Test</Surname>
        <GivenName id="N91">Mary</GivenName>
        <OtherGivenName id="N92">P</OtherGivenName>
      </PersonName>
      <CommlName id="N116">
        <CommercialName id="N117">School District</CommercialName>
      </CommlName>
    </NameInfo>
    <Addr id="N119">
      <AddrTypeCd id="N118">EmployerAddress</AddrTypeCd>
      <Addr1 id="N120">100 Applewild</Addr1>
      <City id="N121">Lady Lake</City>
      <StateProvCd id="N122">FL</StateProvCd>
      <PostalCode id="N123">33333-4444</PostalCode>
    </Addr>
  </GeneralPartyInfo>
</PersDriver>
```

how do I get the field to show 'Test Mary'?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide. Sorry if this is a duplicate of another question I didn't quite know what to search for.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: How is `PersDriver` related to `AccidentViolation`? Does it immediately follow it in the XML? Can there be more than one?  You've omitted the enclosing `AccidentViolations` tag so we can't see the structure of the document.  Without that it will be hard to help.

Comment: @JimGarrison It would seem that they are related by the relation `AccidentViolation/@DriverRef` = `PersDriver/@id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using keys. Put this near the top of your XSLT, inside the `xsl:stylesheet` element and outside of any `xsl:template` elements:

```
<xsl:key name="kPers" match="PersDriver" use="@id" />
```

Then you can do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="a1driver" 
              select="key('kPers', PersPolicy/AccidentViolation[1]/@DriverRef)" />
<Field>
    <Name>Accident1_Name</Name>
    <Value>
        <xsl:variable name="name" 
                      select="$a1driver/GeneralPartyInfo/NameInfo/PersonName" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($name/Surname, ' ', $name/GivenName)" />
    </Value>
    <Type>Tx</Type>
</Field>
```

`$a1driver` should be a reference to the driver's `PersDriver` element, and you can use it to get any other information about the driver that you need.

A more dynamic way to do this for multiple drivers (like you're doing in the answer you posted) is to use `for-each` or `template`s:

```
<xsl:for-each select="PersPolicy/AccidentViolation">
    <xsl:variable name="driver" select="key('kPers', @DriverRef)" />
    <Field>
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="concat('Accident', position(), '_Name')" /></Name>
        <Value>
            <xsl:variable name="name" 
                          select="$driver/GeneralPartyInfo/NameInfo/PersonName" />
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($name/Surname, ' ', $name/GivenName)" />
        </Value>
        <Type>Tx</Type>
    </Field>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: "*Put this near the top of your XSLT, insde the `xsl:template` element:*" It should read **outside**: `xsl:key` is a top-level element.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks! I meant to say `xsl:stylesheet`. I guess mistakes like that can happen when writing answers at 4:30am. :)